# Pandas - performing aggregation based on list of columns in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pivot-table

I want to perform a loop to sum (column: want) based on a list of columns stored as a dictionary. The loop outputs uses the underlying dataset d1 and performs a pivot operation and then outputs multiple datasets d_new1 and d_other1 based on the columns specified in the loop (dictionary). I am having troubles referencing the column name in the aggregation step from the dictionary.
The formula for column "want" in the two datasets d_new1 and d_other1 is shown in the image below.
[image: An tabular version of the image is attached]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col3': [3, 4],'col4': [3, 4], 'something2': [1, 2], 'something3': [3, 4], 'something4': [3, 4]})

for key, value in {'new1':[['col1'],{'col3':'mean','col4':'mean'}], 'other1':[['col3'],{'something3':'sum','something4':'sum'}] }.items():
    exec(f"d_{key}=pd.pivot_table(d1, index=value[0], aggfunc=value[1]).reset_index()")
    print(exec(f"d_{key}"))
    # for d_new1, I want to add column col3 and col4, whereas for d_other1, i want to add something3 + something4
    #exec(f"d_{key}['want']=d_{key}[list(value[1].keys())[0]] + d_{key}[list(value[1].keys())[1]]")
    # output:
    #exec(f"d_{key}['want']=d_{key}[list(value[1].keys())[0]] + d_{key}[list(value[1].keys())[1]]")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was right in front of me. I just had to rearrange and simplify this code.

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col3': [3, 4],'col4': [3, 4], 'something2': [1, 2], 'something3': [3, 4], 'something4': [3, 4]})

for key, value in {'new1':[['col1'],{'col3':'mean','col4':'mean'}], 'other1':[['col3'],{'something3':'sum','something4':'sum'}] }.items(): 
    dt=pd.pivot_table(d1, index=value[0], aggfunc=value[1]).reset_index()
    dt['want']=dt[list(value[1].keys())[0]] + dt[list(value[1].keys())[1]]
    exec(f"d_{key}=dt")

print(d_new1)
print(d_other1)
```